# Query regarding OSM file structure

Tags: openstreetmap

Had a query regarding the OSM file's tags and values. I came across files where there are inconsistencies in tag names and certain node ids/uids do not have tag names and thereby don't allow us to identify what feature it is without opening them in any GIS software. For example, some node ids and uids have tag names as "source bing". Is there a way to identify what they represent without opening them in GIS software? Also, How does OSM recognize these features without proper tag names and values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the OSM data model, nodes can represent point features, but they can also be used to define the shape of ways (or, rarely, relations). OSM ways do not have location information on their own, but instead reference a list of node IDs. You can read more about this in the [OSM wiki's article on nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). The OSM wiki is also a good source on the meaning of the tags used in the OSM database.

Nodes that do not represent a point feature will usually carry no tags. However, you will sometimes find nodes with tags for internal use by OSM contributors, such as [source](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:source) information.

There are other reasons why a node may have no tags or unexpected tags, such as editing mistakes by an OSM contributor or newly invented tags. But these are comparatively less common.